# How to call an external Javascript function in a dynamic action?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I have a dynamic action set to trigger when a user presses a button. However I am well above the limit for the JavaScript I can put into the text box. I have uploaded my function as a .js file to the static file shared components part of the application.

However, I am at a loss as to how to now call that function when the dynamic action triggers. Also my JavaScript relies on form entries on the page it's being called from as it uses that data as variables.

How can I set the page to be able to call the function from the external .js file? Preferably in as step-by-step fashion as possible as I am still very new to Apex.

Comment: Do you have any sample code you can post to help explain this a bit? In short, you will need to ensure your `.js` file is included in the HTML output, and you should then be able to call your functions.

Comment: Right now even just parsing the form data into arrays is too much. 

-
```function parse() {col_01 = [
apex.item('P7_A').getValue(),
apex.item('P7_B').getValue(),
apex.item('P7_C').getValue(),
apex.item('P7_D').getValue(),
apex.item('P7_E').getValue()
]}```
-
is the content of the js file (for now, I have over 50 of these to parse). How do I make sure the .js file is included in the HTML output?

Comment: One additional note... if you have ~50+ fields to extract values from, consider putting that list of fields into an array and just extracting the values in a loop. e.g. `function parse(){
    var fields = ['P7_A', 'P7_B', 'P7_C', 'P7_D', 'P7_E',...];
    var col_01 = [];
    for(var i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
         col_01.push(apex.item(fields[i]).getValue());
    }
    return col_01;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did well to add it to the static files, but you have to tell your app that you have an external js file.

There are two options to do this:

1. In the page properties if you are only going to use the function on that page. Editing the javascript File URLs option

[image]

2. In shared Components, in the details of User Interface Attributes.If you are going to use the function throughout the application.

[image]

After that, simply use your function on the trigger